# Transform multiplicative noise to additive noise with singular matrices

Tags: stochastic-processes, inverse, stochastic-differential-equations, pseudoinverse

I have a stochastic differential equation with multiplicative noise $\alpha(t)$

\begin{equation}
   \dot{\textbf{X}}=\textbf{A}\textbf{X}+\alpha(t)\textbf{B}\textbf{X}-\alpha^*(t)\textbf{B}^T\textbf{X}
\end{equation}

where $T$ is the transpose and the stochastic variable $\alpha(t)$ is a complex-variable Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. Physically, I have a set of variables $\textbf{X}$ driven by colored noise.

Important here is that $X$ and $B$ can be either column vectors or matrices, both representations are the same. If the problem would be 1-D, then I wouldn't have any problem.

My plan is to use UCNA method to solve it (http://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/theo1/hanggi/Papers/79.pdf). However, the key step is to transform my stochastic differential equation with multiplicative noise into a stochastic differential equation with additive noise. And here is where the problem starts:

1. $\textbf{B}$ is singular, so I cannot invert them and isolate the variable $\alpha(t)$.
2. Even if I could invert one of them $\textbf{B}^{-1}$, I would still get $\textbf{B}^{-1}\textbf{B}^T$, which it doesn't have to be the identity.

So my questions are: what can be done considering I have a singular matrix? Is there a way to solve for both $\textbf{B}$ and $\textbf{B}^T$? Mathematically, I have heard one can use the Moore–Penrose inverse, however, this does not allow me to isolate $\alpha(t)$.

My goal is to find the steady-state (the long-term) value of the average of , i.e. $\overline{(t\rightarrow \infty)}$.

Note: If the OU process is slow enough (static limit), I know how to solve it: I can assume that ()=, then everything is time-independent, I can solve the exponential and then average over the OU distribution. I want now the quasi-slow limit, the OU process is slow but still time-dependent

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150036/discussion-on-question-by-j-agusti-transform-multiplicative-noise-to-additive-no); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.